# Query parameters and url are not getting updated correctly

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-router

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,

  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {  //subscribe to param change
      console.log('params', params)

  }

  updateQueryParams(queryParam:any): void {

    this.router.navigate([],
      {
        queryParams: queryParams,
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      })
  }
```

If initially my url is just `http://localhost:8080/emp-search`and I send this object to query Param,

```
{name:'test', email: 'test'}
```

the route updates correctly to `http://localhost:8080/emp-search?name=test&email=test` and param change are caught in my `ngOnInit()`

After that if I call my `updateQueryParams()` method again and send this object as queryParams `{name:'test'}`. The url doesn't update and stays `http://localhost:8080/emp-search?name=test&email=test` and no param changes are caught in the `ngOnInit()`

However, if I instead send this object

```
{name:'test', email: 'test', id: '1'}
```

the url updates correctly to this `http://localhost:8080/search?name=test&email=test$id=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "queryParamsHandling: 'merge'" from navigate options In your "updateQueryParams" function and it should work